# Angular 2/4 : Tried to find bootstrap code,

Tags: javascript, angular, command-line-interface, bootstrapping

I'm working on angular 2 project , every thing was working okey and after that it seems that angular got an update to release 4and the project won't work again and this error appear to me :

> Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically
>   analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins
>   options.

here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "untitled",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

main.ts file :

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';


import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';


const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

some help please !

Comment: You're calling `bootstrapModule` twice in main.ts. Try to remove duplicate.

Comment: thank  you    now it is working  ^_^

Comment: I had this same error message when the path to one of my modules was incorrect. - Corrected the path and error message was gone.

Comment: Got this error when I accidentally deleted my app.module.ts file.  Dumb mistake, I know, but hopefully someone will read this and check before pulling out their hair.